# Texture doesn't reach all surfaces

Tags: vertices, texture-painting, color

This is a texture that am trying to color with but it doesn't looks like it reaches out all places. There are places that I can't color with.[image]

[image]

Update

Since I got a really good comment on that said to me to use the UV Editor to Color the texture and it got working this is a not bad solution for it. I was upsetting on with the vertices thinking that the issue was within they and this is the fourth time I try to do this. again thanks n.n

Comment: What happens if you try to paint those faces in the UV Image Editor instead of the 3d viewport? Does the paint not apply there, or do you find it does recolor the pixels?  Sometimes the Occlude and Backface Culling can cause the 3d view to miss when painting - for a solid fill like this, you can try temporarily turning those off to see if the paint shows up on the faces.

Comment: thanks it did it n.n.